# На Android стало храниться только одно QML-приложение

Tags: android, qt, qml, настройка

В один прекрасный момент мобильник Huawei Honor 6 без моего согласия молча накатил обновления, снес все программы, и сбросил все настройки включая язык, страну, часовой пояс и т.п. В итоге сейчас стоит Android 6.0 с EMUI 4.0.1.

Вместе с этим изменилось поведение при USB-отладке QML-приложений. Если раньше приложение оставалось на телефоне, и разные QML-приложения имели отдельные значки с дефолтной иконкой «зеленый робот», то теперь на телефоне сохраняется только одно QML-приложение. То есть при запуске абсолютно другого QML-приложения в режиме USB, зачем-то удаляется предыдущее QML-приложение.

Я не могу понять, как с этим бороться. Мне нужно иметь на телефоне несколько QML-приложений, которые будут оставаться на нем и после отладки. Но QML-приложение просто «заменяется» последним отлаживаемым приложением.

Что сделать для того, чтобы на мобильнике оставались все отлаживаемые приложения?

Comment: а в симуляторе, всё ок осталось? Может в обновлении, появились доп. опции в Developer options?

Comment: Проверь, что у тебя в манифесте указано в названии приложения. Вполне может быть, что у тебя там по умолчанию одно и то же написано и телефон считает, что это всё одно программа и сносит твои старые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема оказалась в том, что QtCreator по-умолчанию для всех проектов создает файл AndroidManifest.xml с указанием одного и того же имени пакета (package) как "org.qtproject.example".

Старые версии Android (v. 4.x) позволяли устанавливать программы с одинаковыми именами пакетов как отдельные программы. Android 6.x стал считать такие пакеты одной и той же программой.

Решение: прописать в файле AndroidManifest.xml уникальное имя пакета:

```
<manifest package="ru.mysite.myprogramm" ...
```

Перед этим действием необходимо не забыть создать [шаблон настройки Android - приложения](https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/15152387000yw7edw6ze). И именно в этом шаблоне будет находиться файл AndroidManifest.xml, который и нужно редактировать.